# Exception calling "fill" with "1" arguments: "Invalid object name **TableName**"

Tags: mysql, sql, .net, powershell

I have an sql query to get the print date for a particular batch number that I have obtained from a csv, I am getting an error saying

> ```
> "Exception calling "fill" with "1" arguments: Invalid object name someTableName"
> ```

I have written the query and I have been trying to add it to the table to retrieve it. I am getting the above error

*****SQL connection before this******

```
$sqlCommand1 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlCommand1.Connection = $sqlConnection
$SqlCommand1.CommandText = "SELECT log.FINDATE 
                            FROM JS_BATCHES  log 
                            WHERE BATCHID ='$firstElement'" //obtained this from csv

$sqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$sqlAdapter.SelectCommand=$sqlCommand1
$dataset=New-Object System.Data.DataSet

$sqlAdapter.Fill($dataset)
$sqlConnection.Close();
$wholeData=$dataset.Tables[0]


foreach($row in $wholeData) 
{
  $value=row.FINDATE
}
```

Comment: What does your `$sqlConnection` look like?  Does it specify your database name?

Comment: yes...I have tested the connection and it looks fine